# A Game of Hand Cricket - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple game, in the below function handCricketBat(), the if conditional statement is getting skipped even when the condition batsMan = bowlerMan is satisfied. It always moves on to the else statement. Can someone tell me why this is happening.

```
function handCricketBat(){
        var total = 0;
        for (x = 1; x <=6; x++){
            var batsMan = prompt("Ball " + x + " \nEnter Between 1-6");
            var bowlerMan = randomBall();
            console.log("The bowler - "+ bowlerMan);
            if (batsMan === bowlerMan) {
                console.log("Howzattt");
                break;

            }
            else if (batsMan !== bowlerMan) {
                console.log("That's good batiing, scoring a " + batsMan);
                continue;

            }
            total += +batsMan;

        }
        console.log(total);
    }

    function randomBall(){
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*7);
    }
```

Comment: I think the batsMan you prompt is a String but your bowlerMan in an Interger and because of your "===" comparison, it go to else

Comment: FYI: the `else if` is redundant, a simple `else` is enough

Comment: An article you could read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Answer (score 1):

Your `batsMan` is a string.

Use `var batsMan = parseInt(prompt("Ball " + x + " \nEnter Between 1-6"));` instead and it should work.